# How to read a vector as input user in R

Tags: r, vector, input, readline

I'm new using R and while I was working I had a question that I haven't been able to solve for myself. I would like to create a script or sequence in the console which let user introduce a vector as input, but not any vector, in particular, I need to introduce the vector: `j<-c(1:20,4,30:35)`.

However, if I've tried to use:

```
limStr <- readline("Enter the vector you want:");
Enter the vector you want: j<-c(1:20,4,30:35)
lim <- as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(limStr, ",")));
```

And I have got  `lim= NA 4 NA`

Could someone help me with this problem? How should I write the sequences? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the (in)famous `eval(parse(text = ...)` construct:

```
limStr <- readline("Enter the vector you want:");
Enter the vector you want: c(1:20, 4, 30:35);    
lim <- eval(parse(text = limStr));
lim;
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20  4 30 31 32 33
#[26] 34 35
```

---

On second thought, I'm not entirely sure what you want. If this is about extracting the comma separated terms, you can do

```
unlist(strsplit(gsub("(c\\(|\\))", "", limStr), ", "));
#[1] "1:20"  "4"     "30:35"
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Thanks for your help.

Comment: Great, glad to help @Víctor